# Count if a cell has the same value as another one in the same column

Tags: google-sheets, formula

I'm trying to find a formula to count the number of times, in a given row, a cell has the same value as another one in another row (same column)

Basically, I have something like

```
-----------------
| 1 | S | M | M |
-----------------
| 2 | M | M | M |
-----------------
| 0 | S | M | S |
-----------------
| 1 | S | M | M |
-----------------
| 3 | M | S | M |
-----------------
....
|   | M | S | M |  // <--- the reference row
-----------------
```

The numbers 1, 2, 0, 1, 3 are to be calculated with the formula.
1 -> Only one matches the reference row, which is the last M
2 -> There are two matches, first cell and last cell

Etc...

I have tried stuff like `=COUNTIF(E5:Z5, "="&INDIRECT(ADDRESS(21,COLUMN(),2)))`.
But the `COLUMN()` has the value of the column where this is written and not the value of the column that is being evaluated in the `COUNTIF()`.

If a general way, I can't seem to find a way to refer to the cell being currently evaluated in the `COUNTIF`.

May someone has the answer :).

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be easier with Sumproduct:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((B1:Z1=B$21:Z$21)*(B1:Z1<>""))
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried it but it gives me a #N/A "Error: Array arguments to MULTIPLY are of different size."

Comment: No, wait. I forgot to change one value (from B to E). It actually works! Thanks :-)